# Use of sed (linux)?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace all strin $PHP_SELF by $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in files index.php... But it seems that my syntax is wong:

```
sed -i 's/\$PHP_SELF/\$_SERVER\[\'PHP_SELF\'\]/g' index.php
```

Any idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i .bak "s/\\\$PHP_SELF/\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']/g" index.php
```

Comment: @user2670167, my version of `sed` requires `-i` to be followed by an extension to add to the file before changing it. I suppose other `sed`s are different.

Comment: I've used a recursive command, but unfortunately it removes the `$PHP_SELF` only :-((
Now I'm trying to put it back but without success: `cd /home/trente/public_html/includes && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i.php -pe "s/,\)\)\ \{/,\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {/g"`

Comment: @user2670167, you should post that as a separate question.